# I am writing a lex code in which the regular expression section is given exactly like in the detailed section. Main problem I have is the RE for text

Tags: c, compiler-construction, lex

```c
    %{
    #define  FUNCT      300
    #define  IDENTIFIER 301
    #define  ASSGN      302
    #define  INTEGER    303
    #define  PRINT      304
    #define  TEXT       305
    #define  INPUT      306
    #define  CONTINUE   307
    #define  RETURN     308
    #define  IF         309
    #define  THEN       310
    #define  ENDIF      311
    #define  ELSE       312
    #define  WHILE      313
    #define  DO         314
    #define  ENDDO      315
    #define  END        316
    
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    
    #define MAX_SYM 200
    int found;
    void initialize();   
    void create(char *lexeme, int scope, char type, char usage);
    int readsymtab(char *lexeme, int scope, char usage); 
    %}
    
    %%
    [\t ]+                {}
    =                     {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(ASSGN)                            ;}
    print                 {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');   //line 39
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(PRINT)                            ;}
    input                 {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(INPUT)                            ;}
    continue              {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(CONTINUE)                         ;}
    return                {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(RETURN)                           ;}
    if                    {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(IF)                               ;}
    then                  {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(THEN)                             ;}
    endif                 {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(ENDIF)                            ;}
    else                  {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(ELSE)                             ;}
    while                 {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(WHILE)                            ;}
    do                    {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(DO)                               ;}
    enddo                 {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(ENDDO)                            ;}
    end                   {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(END);
                           exit(0);                                 ;}
    funct                 {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(FUNCT)                            ;}
    [0-9]+                {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'I','L');
                           };
                           return(FUNCT)                            ;}
    [a-zA-Z]+             {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'I');
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','I');
                           };
                           return(IDENTIFIER)                       ;}
    \"[^\"\n]+|[\\n]+\"   {int found = readsymtab(yytext,0,'L');  //line130
                           if(found == -1)
                           {
                            create(yytext,0,'S','L');
                           };
                           return(TEXT)                             ;}
    .                     {return(yytext[0])                        ;}
    %%
    
    
    
    //new variable declaration
    
    int num;
    int scope;
    struct symbtab                    
    {
        char Lexeme [18];
        int Scope;
        char Type;
        char Usage;
        int Reference;
    };
    struct symbtab arr_symtab[200];                                //data structure in which the symbol table entries are stored
    
    void print_fn()                                                //function which actually prints the symbol tabel in columnar form             
    {
        int rows;
        
        printf("Row No Lexeme           Scope Type Usage Reference\n");
    
        for (rows=0; rows<=num; rows++){
            printf("%6d %-16s %-7d %-7c %-7c %-7d \n",rows, arr_symtab[rows].Lexeme,arr_symtab[rows].Scope,arr_symtab[rows].Type,arr_symtab[rows].Usage,arr_symtab[rows].Reference);
        }
    }
    
    void initialize()                                              //function which enteres the initial value into the symbol table              
    {
        num = -1;
        int scope = 0;
        char lexeme[18]= "FRED";
        char type = 'I';
        char usage = 'L';
        create(lexeme,scope,type,usage);   
    }
    
    void create(char *lexeme, int scope, char type, char usage)    //function which creates a new entry in the symbol table                                                                     
    {
        
        int reference;
        if(type=='I' && usage =='L')
             reference = atoi(lexeme);
        else
             reference = -1;
    
        num = num+1;
        strcpy(arr_symtab[num].Lexeme, lexeme); 
        arr_symtab[num].Scope = scope;
        arr_symtab[num].Type = type;
        arr_symtab[num].Usage = usage;
        arr_symtab[num].Reference = reference;
        
    }
    
    int readsymtab(char *lexeme, int scope, char usage)                 //function which checks if the entry is already in the table or not and the takes the required action                                                              
    {
        for(int i=num; i>=0; i--){
            int comp = strcmp(arr_symtab[i].Lexeme, lexeme);
           if(comp==0 && arr_symtab[i].Scope==scope && arr_symtab[i].Usage==usage)
           {
               return i;
           }
           else
           {
               return -1;
           }
        }
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        //other lines
        printf("\n COURSE: CSCI50200 NAME: Aryan Banyal NN: 01 Assignment #: 04 \n");
        initialize();
        yylex();
        print_fn();
        printf("End of test.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    int yywrap ()
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

Following is the output for print"aryan banyal"

```
     COURSE: CSCI50200 NAME: Aryan Banyal NN: 01 Assignment #: 04 
    --(end of buffer or a NUL)
    --accepting rule at line 39 ("print")
    Row No Lexeme           Scope Type Usage Reference
         0 FRED             0       I       L       0       
         1 print            0       S       L       -1      
    End of test.
```

As you can see it's not even going to the "aryan banyal" part just does the print thing and exits...
Following is the output for "aryan banyal"

```
     COURSE: CSCI50200 NAME: Aryan Banyal NN: 01 Assignment #: 04 
    --(end of buffer or a NUL)
    --accepting rule at line 130 (""aryan banyal")
    Row No Lexeme           Scope Type Usage Reference
         0 FRED             0       I       L       0       
         1 "aryan banyal    0       S       L       -1      
    End of test.
```

It shoud be aryan banyal there on Row No 1 but there a " before for some reason.

Comment: The pattern `\"[^\"\n]+|[\\n]+\"` doesn't make any sense to me. Can you supply a simple, clear explanation of what you think it matches? You should try to supply actual evidence about what your program does, rather than trying to explain it in a foreign language. The simplest way to trace execution is to use flex's `-d` option when you build the lexer. Then you can cut and paste what it prints. Don't forget to include your input.

Comment: I am sorry I am kind of a noob to all this, what do you mean trace execution... where do I put -d? When I am flexing the .l file or when I am compiling with gcc?

Comment: When you invoke flex (or lex, which is probably an alias on your machine). It's a flex option, not a gcc option. By the way, you should read at least a part of the fine [flex manual](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/index.html).

Comment: Well, my input was print"aryan banyal" and it says in the terminal that it's accepting the print rule but it never went to the other rule. If I put "aryan banyal" as input it says that--accepting rule at line 130 (""aryan banyal") but it stores "aryan banyal in the symbol table... it should store aryan banyal.

Comment: "The simplest way to trace execution is to use flex's -d option when you build the lexer. **Then you can cut and paste what it prints.**" (emphasis added from first time) (Copy it **into your question**, using the edit button, not into a comment.) If the line numbers in your code are not obvious, please indicate using comments.

Comment: The first step in learning how to ask clear questions is to learn how to provide all useful data :-) And learning to ask clear questions is almost important as learning how to debug your own code.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry that was my bad again. It's my first time asking a question here so thanks for letting me know the good practices. I have included the whole code with expected and actual output with execution trace. If there anything else I can provide to make help you understand my problem please do let me know.

Comment: For future reference, from the SO help: [ask] and how to create a [mre]. (The important thing about minimal reproducible examples is that they are reduced to a minimum *but* still can be compiled and run. That means making a new program with a lot fewer details -- like all of your keywords -- which still exhibits the same problem.

Comment: I will keep that in mind from the next time. thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have (at least) three (somewhat) unrelated problems.

#### Using the lexical scanner

Your code stops after reading a single token because you only call `yylex()` once (and ignore what it returns). `yylex()` returns a single token every time you call it; if you want to scan the entire file, you need to call it in a loop. It will return 0 when it encounters the end of input.

#### Understanding patterns

The pattern `\"[^\"\n]+|[\\n]+\"` has an `|` in the middle; that operator matches either of the patterns which surround it. So you are matching `\"[^\"\n]+` **or** `[\\n]+\"`. The first one matches a single double quote, followed by any number of characters (but at least one), which cannot be a quote or a new line. So that matches `"aryan banyal` without the closing quote but including the open quote. The second half of the alternative would match any number of characters (again, at least one) all of which are either a backslash or the letter `n`, and then a single double quote.

(I don't understand the thinking behind this pattern, and it is almost certainly not what you intended. Had you called `yylex` again after the match of `"aryan banyal`, the closing quote would *not* have been matched, because it would be the immediate next character, and the pattern insists that it be preceded by at least one backslash or `n`. (Maybe you intended that to be a newline, but there is not one of those either.)

I think you probably wanted to match the entire quoted string, and then to keep only the part between the quotes. If you had written the pattern correctly, that's what it would have matched, and then you would need to remove the double quotes. I'll leave writing the correct pattern as an exercise. You might want to read the short [description of Flex patterns](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html) in the Flex manual; you probably also have some information in your class notes.

#### Selecting just a part of the match

It's easy to remove the quote at the beginning of the token. All that requires is adding one to `yytext`. To get rid of the one at the end, you need to overwrite it with a `\0`, thereby terminating the string one character earlier. That's easy to do because Flex provides you with the length of the match in the variable `yyleng`. So you could set `yytext[yyleng - 1] = '\0'` and then call your symbol table function with `yytext + 1`.

If the above paragraph did not make sense, you should review any introductory text on string processing in C. Remember that in C, a string is nothing but an array of single characters (small integers) terminated with a 0. That's makes some things very easy to do, and other things a bit painful (but never mysterious).

Comment: Oh my god! thanks wow that actually worked! nice... I will also read the description of flex pattren documentation that you provided and thanks for such timely and quick answers!!!